# Streamline when/otherwise logic using a udf - Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I need to create a single column based on other columns with following logic: zyx>abc>pep>none. I need to do that for several subsets of columns thats why the usual when/otherwise would be ineffective. Can this be automated with a udf perhaps where I pass a list of column names?

Here is an example of a subset of columns and expected outcome in col5:

```
  col1     col2      col3      col4    (...)     col5
  zyx      pep       abc       pep     (...)     zyx
  pep      pep       abc       pep     (...)     abc
  abc      pep       pep       pep     (...)     abc
  abc      pep       pep       pep     (...)     abc
  pep      pep       pep       pep     (...)     pep
  pep      pep       pep       zyx     (...)     zyx
```

Comment: x, y, z is a literal string?  are you trying to get the smallest value (if character, earlier letter in alphabet) in a row between col1 - col4?

Comment: These are strings and actual words, not letters. The priority would need to be fixed rather than set up by alphabetical order.

Comment: Could you update to reflect that?  As it stands, it looks like it is alphabetical order and the solution would be different if your data is not character and not alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it and I don't use udf as udf tends to be slow.

```py
from itertools import chain

sort_mapping = {
    'zyx': 1,
    'abc': 2,
    'pep': 3    
}

reverse_mapping = {value: key for key, value in sort_mapping.items()}

# Make map objects to be referenced from the Pyspark functions.
sort_mapping = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*sort_mapping.items())])
reverse_mapping = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*reverse_mapping.items())])

col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
df = (df.withColumn('arr', F.array(col_list))
      .withColumn('arr', F.array_min(F.transform('arr', lambda x: sort_mapping[x])))
      .withColumn('col5', reverse_mapping[F.col('arr')]))
```

Explanation:

First, collect all columns in concern into an array.

```
.withColumn('arr', F.array(col_list))
```

Then, transform the array with the sorting order value. (ie: zyx -> 1, abc -> 2)

```
F.transform('arr', lambda x: mapping_expr[x]))
```

And take a minimum of the array with `array_min`.

Finally, map the value back to the original string. (ie: 1 -> zyc, 2 -> abc)

```
.withColumn('col5', reverse_mapping[F.col('arr')])
```

#### Update

For <Pyspark3.1,

```
df = (df.withColumn('arr', F.array('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'))
      .withColumn('sort_mapping', sort_mapping)
      .withColumn('arr', F.array_min(F.expr(f'transform(arr, x -> sort_mapping[x])')))
      .withColumn('col5', reverse_mapping[F.col('arr')]))
```

I added the `sort_mapping` into a column to be accessible from raw `expr` and use raw SQL's transform.

Comment: this only works with 3.1+. If you are using lower version of Spark, please let me know

Comment: wow, need to grab a cup of coffe before I go through all this! Definately did not expect it to be this complex.

Comment: It is totally possible that there is a better way.  Also, if it is regular alphabetical order, you can simply use `F.least` or `F.greatest` but with the custom order, it gets complicated

Comment: yes so like you mentioned I am using spark 3.0.1 so F.transform is not available

Comment: updated for lower version.

Comment: Looked at it with a fresh pair of eyes today and it works great. Does exactly what I needed. I can now create a dict with column names and list of columns and run it using a for loop. Really appreciate your help!